# How do I keep files not associated with the project in XCode 4 without generating a warning

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

I recently upgraded to XCode 4 and adjusting. I have a folder called "Unused" in which I keep some .h and .m files. They are basically code which are no longer associated with the project and I keep them because they serve as a reference. The compiler doesn't look what it sees in there so I change the .h and .m files to .h.txt and .m.txt. However, I get this warning:

```
warning: no rule to process file '$(PROJECT_DIR)/Classes/AddViewController.m.txt' of type text for architecture i386
```

Does anyone have any solution for this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select the target in XCode, then in the Build Phases tab, under Compile Sources, remove the unused files that you don't want.  XCode will only compile the files listed.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the files to link, you can select the relevant file on the left side project navigator, then go to your right side bar and select the File inspector (left most icon on top right bar), then scroll down to "Target Membership" and unclick the checkbox so the file is not associated with any of your targets.